# Quirk with blocking video ads in YouTube with Firefox and AdBlock Plus

Tags: firefox, youtube, adblock

I am an IE9 user and got tired of YouTube forcing me to wait 15 seconds to watch an ad before I could watch the video that I wanted.

So I installed ABP for Firefox and the ads went away!  However, if I actually log in to YouTube with FF, ABP fails to block the ads.  I am assuming it's something cookie-related because I can fix it by clearing all cookies again which results in me no longer being logged in.

Right now I am using IE9 for regular viewing, but switch over to FF if I come upon a video that tries to force me to sit through a 15-second ad (I don't want to do that).  The problem is that some vids are flagged as inappropriate for some viewers and requires me to log in.  Of course, when I do this, I have to watch the ad.  I don't want to watch them, though.

I'd like to get this to work with FF so I can use FF as my primary YouTube browser.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing you can do about this.  Adblock on YouTube is experimental.  When you actually log into YouTube the ads are streamed to you and are not able to be blocked.